# Why no warning when using as.numeric() on factor?

Tags: r

I 'd like to undestand why `R` does not warn the user when applying `as.numeric()` on a `factor`. I happened to note this while reading a csv file whose columns where read `as.factor()` by `R` :

- Data : [BB.TO](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/BB.TO/history?period1=882162000&period2=1568347200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d) through yahoo finance. Clicking on "Download data" will download the following file : `BB.TO.csv`
- Let's read the data and compute the mean of the `Adj.Close` column :

```
mydf <- read.csv("BB.TO.csv")
mydf$Adj.Close <- as.numeric(mydf$Adj.Close)
mean(mydf$Adj.Close)
```

Here's the console output :

> ```
> > mydf <- read.csv("BB.TO.csv")
> > mydf$Adj.Close <- as.numeric(mydf$Adj.Close)
> > mean(mydf$Adj.Close)
> [1] 1759.939
> ```

No warning, nothing. However, R read the strings as factor and replaced any `"null"` values by the total number of levels (3722) without it ever warning the user ...

- Reading with `stringAsFactors` :

```
mydf <- read.csv("BB.TO.csv", stringsAsFactors=F)
mydf$Adj.Close <- as.numeric(mydf$Adj.Close)
mean(mydf$Adj.Close)
```

And here's the output :

> ```
> > mydf <- read.csv("BB.TO.csv", stringsAsFactors=F)
> > mydf$Adj.Close <- as.numeric(mydf$Adj.Close)
> Warning message:
> NAs introduced by coercion 
> > mean(mydf$Adj.Close)
> [1] NA
> ```

Now, we have a warning ...

I guess my **question** is why is `R` taking such a wild guess by default without warning the user? What is the logic behind this ?

Comment: Because it is coeced to integer storage mode values.   Check `v1 <- factor(letters[1:5]); as.numeric(v1)` `mean` also has `na.rm = TRUE` if there are `NA` elements in your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just some of the logic of factors in R. Technically factors are represented as integer values in R with labels attached. This saves memory (one set of labels, the rest of the memory can be devoted to just stored integers which take up fewer bytes). So for your question, it kind of is already a numeric type, but with label atached.

Additionally when doing experiments, it makes sense to having preallocated factors or experimental treatments so you would never not know your experimental design. This was the the environment in which R was born and why we have some of these idiosyncratic behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is coerced to integer storage mode values. Check

```
v1 <- factor(letters[1:5])
as.numeric(v1)
```

The `mean` also has `na.rm = TRUE` if there are NA elements in your data